# (CLR) C++/CLI include header in form file?

Tags: forms, header, include, c++-cli

I have a simple form in C++/cli (CLR) and in the file (.h extension, in this case MyForm.h) where MyForm is defined I want to include a header file from "Header Files". However, when I try to include it wherever in the file and attempt to compile it, it returns over 100 errors while building from files that I did not even add(like wingdi.h).
Here's an example

```
#pragma endregion
#include "headerfile.h" //The header I want to include
private: System::Void label1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    System::Windows::Forms::Application::Exit();
}
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

}
private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, 
System::EventArgs^  e) {
}
};
}
```

This code is where button click functions ar defined in MyForm.h

Comment: Headers often include other headers. Without knowing what mystery header you are including and it's contents it's unlikely we can give much assistance.

Comment: I am not sure what code I am supposed to provide. The one in the header that I am trying to include?